# Unable to view api statistics in api manager

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

am trying to integrate the BAM Server(2.2.0) and API Management(1.3.1) getting error:

[2013-05-13 14:59:41,747] ERROR - APIProviderHostObject Error while invoking APIUsageStatisticsClient for ProviderAPIUsage org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.usage.client.exception.APIMgtUsageQueryServiceClientException: Error occurred while querying from JDBC database at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.usage.client.APIUsageStatisticsClient.queryDatabase(APIUsageStatisticsClient.java:715) at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.usage.client.APIUsageStatisticsClient.getAPIFaultyAnalyzeByTime(APIUsageStatisticsClient.java:447) at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.hostobjects.APIProviderHostObject.jsFunction_getAPIFaultyAnalyzeByTime(APIProviderHostObject.java:2141) at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39) at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)

Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Table "API_RESOURCE_PATH_USAGE_SUMMARY" not found; SQL statement:

SELECT * FROM  API_Resource_Path_USAGE_SUMMARY [42102-140]

```
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:327)

    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:167)

    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:144)

    at org.h2.command.Parser.readTableOrView(Parser.java:4498)

    at org.h2.command.Parser.readTableFilter(Parser.java:1011)

    at org.h2.command.Parser.parseSelectSimpleFromPart(Parser.java:1577)

    at org.h2.command.Parser.parseSelectSimple(Parser.java:1682)

    at org.h2.command.Parser.parseSelectSub(Parser.java:1571)

    at org.h2.command.Parser.parseSelectUnion(Parser.java:1416)

    at org.h2.command.Parser.parseSelect(Parser.java:1404)

    at org.h2.command.Parser.parsePrepared(Parser.java:392)

    at org.h2.command.Parser.parse(Parser.java:275)

    at org.h2.command.Parser.parse(Parser.java:247)

    at org.h2.command.Parser.prepare(Parser.java:201)


    at org.h2.command.Parser.prepareCommand(Parser.java:214)

    at org.h2.engine.Session.prepareLocal(Session.java:434)

    at org.h2.engine.Session.prepareCommand(Session.java:384)

    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.prepareCommand(JdbcConnection.java:1071)

    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcStatement.executeQuery(JdbcStatement.java:70)

    at
```

org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.usage.client.APIUsageStatisticsClient.queryDatabase(APIUsageStatisti
csClient.java:697)
        ... 52 more

Answer (score 1):

There are some identified issues with configuring BAM 2.2.0 with APIM 1.3.1. Hence please use BAM 2.0.1 with APIM following[1]

[1]http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/AM131/Monitoring+and+Statistics

Comment: Hi, I took BAM 2.0.1 and tried to integrate. But i got the same error.

Comment: If you haven't invoked any APIs after integrating with BAM, please do so. The tables are created only after script is run and necessary statistics are generated.

Comment: Hi, I Invoked APIS using RestClient(under Tools).